# 'Day after tomorrow' is not working in parsedatetime library of Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I am using `parsedatetime` library of Python for Date time Parsing from Natural Language. It parses Natural Language to date time for many scenarios. For example `next Monday at 5PM`, `next month etc.

But when `day after tomorrow` or `day before yesterday` is given in Natural Language, it does not understand it.

For example, 'day after tomorrow' fetches tomorrow's date time.

Here is the code snippet:

```
from datetime import datetime
import parsedatetime as pdt

plain_text='day after tomorrow'   # Natural Language input

str_parsed_date_time = ''
cal = pdt.Calendar()
now = datetime.now()
for time_string in [plain_text]:
    parsed_date_time = (cal.parseDT(time_string, now)[0])
    str_parsed_date_time = datetime.strftime(parsed_date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # Convert date time to string
print(str_parsed_date_time)
```

Today's date is `April 18th 2017 (2017-04-18)`

**The library outputs 2017-04-19  instead of 2017-04-20**

What could be the reason?

Comment: I think its just not understanding 'day after' or 'day before' 'and returning tomorrow or yesterday date....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parsedatetime` expects to have a quantity in front of its units.  So it will successfully parse something like `a day after tomorrow`, but will not do `day after tomorrow`.

**Test Code:**

```
import parsedatetime as pdt

test_text = [
    'day after tomorrow',
    'the day after tomorrow',
    'a day after tomorrow',
    'an day after tomorrow',
    'one day after tomorrow',
    'two day after tomorrow',
    ]

cal = pdt.Calendar()
for time_string in test_text:
    result = cal.nlp(time_string)[0]
    print("Got: %s  from:'%s'  original:'%s'" % (
        result[0].date(), result[-1], time_string))
```

**Results:**

```
Got: 2017-04-20  from:'after tomorrow'  original:'day after tomorrow'
Got: 2017-04-20  from:'after tomorrow'  original:'the day after tomorrow'
Got: 2017-04-21  from:'a day after tomorrow'  original:'a day after tomorrow'
Got: 2017-04-21  from:'an day after tomorrow'  original:'an day after tomorrow'
Got: 2017-04-21  from:'one day after tomorrow'  original:'one day after tomorrow'
Got: 2017-04-22  from:'two day after tomorrow'  original:'two day after tomorrow'
```

Note that in the first two results, the `from` string does not match the `original` string, because the returned string is the string used in the parse, and `parsedatetime` did recognize the units for the `day` and thus ignored it.